# How to move bonders in Space Chem

Tags: spacechem

I'm playing the tutorial of Space Chem, and I've reached the stage where it tells me I can move the bonders.  And I think I need to move the bonders.  But I cannot get them to move!  Dragging with the left mouse button does not move them.

**How do I move a bonder?**

---

**FOLLOWUP:** thanks for all the help.  It turns out my game had gotten into some strange wedged state.  Exit, restart, and bonders will drag with the left mouse button as expected.

Comment: Dragging with the left mouse button works over here - Have you got your mouse set up for left-handed use, perhaps? (in which case you'd need to drag with the right mouse button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bonders are moved in the same way that instructions are moved after placement - usually this is by clicking on them, holding and dragging them across the field.
(If you are somehow moving instructions in a different way, try that as well)

Note that you *cannot* use a drag-box selection (as you can to pick up multiple instructions), these ignore reactor features such as bonders.

---

If you can't move bonders in the same was as instructions (and maybe you can't move instructions either?), it sounds like you've hit a bug of some type.

As William suggests in a comment, do you have anything unusual with respect to the set up of your input devices? And, have you tried moving the bonders (or different types of reactor features) on different levels in case it's a level specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Moving bonders can be a bit finicky if there is also an instruction in the same square. You have to make sure you click on the light gray bit of bonder that's still visible, not the red/blue instruction.

Hmm, maybe first clicking (instead of dragging straight away) may be key; I'll check and report back later.

Answer (score 1):

Quit, restart, and it will work.

(I know you've already figured this out, but I just had the same problem and this was the answer I needed)

Answer (score 1):

The real key to this is you have to click on the grey circle part of the bonder, not the middle to drag it. It took me a while to figure that out.